# Accessing an Intranet database in SharePoint and make it available on internet

Tags: content-database, intranet

Is it possible with SharePoint to access an Intranet DataBase and get all the data from it and make it available on the Internet online?

The context:

Right now we have an application that manipulates an Intranet database (caché) so it's only available for the intranet. And the thing is that we want to access that Intranet database With Sharepoint and make it available on the internet, online. Is this even possible?

I'm searching for a "no code" solution if possible. But if there's a framework that could do such things and allows us to develop in that kind of environment it's welcome.

Answer (score 1):

i think, you should check the BCS options of SharePoint. BCS will help you connect the other datasource and bring them in SharePoint as List, then you can share that list externally.

for SharePoint 2010: [Business Connectivity Services (Professional SharePoint 2010 Development)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh144965%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#ProSP2010Dev_Ch11_Introduction)

For SharePoint 2013: [Deploy a Business Connectivity Services on-premises](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219584.aspx)

Comment: Just to be sure, when they speak about "External data", it means extarnal to sharepoint right? And can this "External data" be my intranet database then? I don't know about BCS so i will read those links thank you for sharing sir.